# RSelenium: R can't detect new version of chromedriver

Tags: r, selenium-chromedriver, rselenium

I am trying to run RSelenium after a few months. It seems that my chrome browser updated to version 88 while my chromedriver remained in version 86. I proceeded to download chromedriver version 88, but still R is returning me the following error:

```
    Selenium message:session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 86
Current browser version is 88.0.4324.146 with binary path C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
```

I already tried deleting Chromedriver version 86, uninstalling RSelenium, uninstalling google chrome and I cannot figure out what's going wrong.

When checking chromedriver versions within R it gives me the following:

```
binman::list_versions("chromedriver")
$win32
[1] "85.0.4183.83" "85.0.4183.87" "86.0.4240.22"
```

So I don't know why chromedriver for version 86 is still there if I copied version 88.

Comment: Maybe try adding chromedriver path to system environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

I have done:

```
npx webdriver-manager update
```

it gets form:

> installation chromedriver_88.0.4324.96.zip

and now it is working fine.